# Laravel form choosing form

Tags: php, forms, file, laravel-5

I have problem with laravel form and choosing files

```
$language = $request->input('language');

  if($language = "eng"){
    $type = "emails/eng";
  } else if($language = "pl" ){
    $type ="emails/pl"; 
  }
  dump($language);
  dump($type);
```

when I do that in controller I always get the same result with "eng" but when I delete if rules I get "eng" and "pl".

Any help with that ?

Comment: maybe I am wrong, but you are assigning '=' $language value if you want to see if the string is equal you should use '==' in your if statement.

Answer (score 2):

You must use "==" to compare:

```
 if($language == "eng"){
    $type = "emails/eng";
 } else if($language == "pl" ){
    $type ="emails/pl"; 
 }
```